# KivyMD: Accessing Label ID From Screen Class

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am using KivyMD and would like to refrash data in the the secound screen using the "on_pre_enter" method.
I am trying to access a label id from screen class "on_pre_enter" method with out success.

I am able to access the label id from the "MainApp" class but unable to access it from the "Second_Screen" class.

MainApp.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.title = "My Material Application"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_start(self):
        self.root.ids.main_screen_label.text = "Main Screen Updated"

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file("app.kv")


class Second_Screen(Screen):
    def on_pre_enter(self):
        MainApp.ids.second_screen_label = "Second Screen Updated"

    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

App.kv

```
NavigationLayout:
    MDNavigationDrawer:
        NavigationDrawerSubheader:
            text: "Menu:"

        NavigationDrawerIconButton:
            icon:'battery'
            text: "Main Screen"
            on_release:
                screen_manager.current = "main_screen"

        NavigationDrawerIconButton:
            icon:'battery'
            text: "Second Screen"
            on_release:
                screen_manager.current = "second_screen"


    BoxLayout:
        id: box1
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            title: "My App"
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            left_action_items:
                [['menu', lambda x: app.root.toggle_nav_drawer()]]

        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager
            Screen:
                name: "main_screen"
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint: .8, .8
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                    spacing: dp(100)
                    orientation: 'vertical'


                    MDLabel:
                        id: main_screen_label
                        text: "Main Screen Default"

            Second_Screen:
                name: "second_screen"
                FloatLayout:
                    id: float
                    size_hint: .8, .8
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                    spacing: dp(100)
                    orientation: 'vertical'


                    MDLabel:
                        id: second_screen_label
                        text: "Second Screen Default"
```

I also tried using:

```
class Second_Screen(Screen):
    def on_pre_enter(self):
        self.ids.second_screen_label.text = "Second Screen Updated"
    pass
```

After starting the i get the following error:

```
   self.ids.second_screen_label.text = "Second Screen Updated"
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 863, in 
   kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
   AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

What is the correct way to access the id's defined in the KV file from the screen class?

Comment: The `ids` are combined in the `root` of the 'kv' rule where each `id` is declared. So all your `ids` are in the `NavigationLayout` instance.

Comment: Thank you @JohnAnderson.
I tried using:
`test = NavigationLayout.ids.second_screen_label.text
        print(test)`
And got the following error:
`test = NavigationLayout.ids.second_screen_label.text
 AttributeError: 'kivy.properties.DictProperty' object has no attribute 'second_screen_label'`

Comment: `NavigationLayout` is a class, you need the instance of that class. Try `App.get_running_app().root.ids.second_screen_label.text`. That is assuming that the `NavigationLayout` is the root of your `App`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define screen layout in separate rule `<MyScreen>`:

```
<MyScreen>:
    name: "my_screen"

    FloatLayout:
        # ...
```

To add this screen to ScreenManager, just write:

```
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager

        MyScreen:
```

---

To get access to screen widgets use

- from screen class: `self.ids.my_id`
- from app class: `self.root.ids.screen_manager.get_screen("screen_name").ids.my_id`
- from other widgets: `App.get_running_app()..root.ids.screen_manager.get_screen("screen_name").ids.my_id`

---

So your full code will be:

main.py

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.title = "My Material Application"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file("app.kv")

    def on_start(self):
        self.root.ids.screen_manager.get_screen(
            "main_screen"
        ).ids.main_screen_label.text = "Main Screen Updated"


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class SecondScreen(Screen):
    def on_pre_enter(self):
        self.ids.second_screen_label.text = "Second Screen Updated"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

app.kv

```
NavigationLayout:
    MDNavigationDrawer:
        NavigationDrawerSubheader:
            text: "Menu:"

        NavigationDrawerIconButton:
            icon: "battery"
            text: "Main Screen"
            on_release:
                screen_manager.current = "main_screen"

        NavigationDrawerIconButton:
            icon: "battery"
            text: "Second Screen"
            on_release:
                screen_manager.current = "second_screen"


    BoxLayout:
        id: box1
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDToolbar:
            title: "My App"
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            left_action_items:
                [["menu", lambda x: app.root.toggle_nav_drawer()]]

        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager

            MainScreen:
            SecondScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main_screen"

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: .8, .8
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        spacing: dp(100)
        orientation: "vertical"

        MDLabel:
            id: main_screen_label
            text: "Main Screen Default"


<SecondScreen>:
    name: "second_screen"

    FloatLayout:
        id: float
        size_hint: .8, .8
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        spacing: dp(100)
        orientation: "vertical"

        MDLabel:
            id: second_screen_label
            text: "Second Screen Default"
```

Comment: Works grate, Thank you!